# Breaking down a maximal $r$-separated subset of $\mathbb R^d$ into a finite disjoint union of $s$-separated subsets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a maximal $r$-separated subset of $\mathbb R^d$, meaning the distance of any two points in $A$ is at least $r>0$.

claim: For any $s>0$, we can always write $A$ as a finite disjoint union of $s$-separated subsets $A_1,\dots, A_p$ such that $p$ only depends on the ratio $s/r$ and the dimension $d$. (Thanks to the comments below. To be more precise, I want the minimal possible value of $p$ among all decompositions to be bounded by a function that only depends on $s/r$ and $d$. )

When $s\le r$, we can simply take $p=1$ and $A=A_1$.

When $s>r$, my idea is that we first take a maximal $s$-separated subset $A_1$ of $A$ and then take a maximal $s$-separated subset $A_2$ of $A-A_1$ and so on. But I don't see why this has to stop in finite steps and the number of steps only depends on $s/r$ and $d$. For high dimensions this is not easy to picture.

In the original problem I am working on $s/r$ is an integer, but I guess that is not necessary. Please let me know if it matters. This might be related to some famous theory I don't know about.

Comment: What do you mean by "$p$ only depends on $s/r$ and $d$" precisely ? For instance if $A$ is the disjoint union of $A_1,\cdots,A_p$, one can cut $A_1$ in two and get $A$ as a disjoint union of $p+1$ $s$-separated subsets

Comment: @AlexL I mean there is an algorithm for this splitting such that the $p$ produced only depends on the ratio $s/r$, but not the specific values if s and r. p may also depend on d.

Comment: I don't understand in your claim : Are the separated subsets demanded to be maximal in $A$ ? And do you want $p$ to be an exact value which is a function of $s/r$ and $d$, and such that $p$ doesn't depends on $A$ maximal in $\mathbb{R}^d$ ?

Comment: In my answer below I can't guarantee that the disjoint $s$-separated $A_i$'s are maximal in $A$. $A_i$ is only maximal in $A \setminus (A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{i-1})$

Comment: @AlexL to be more precise, I want the minimal possible value of p among all decompositions to be bounded by a function that only depends on s/r and d. I think if A is not maximal this is not true: just take two points with distance (s+r)/2

Comment: In my answer it is shown that a bound is the maximal number of disjoint balls of radius $r$ that fit into a ball of radius $s$. And I don't assume $A$ to be maximal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give below an argument to show that $A$ is indeed a $\textit{finite}$ union of $s$-separated subsets. But you claim needs to be more precise.

Assume $s>r$. Let $N$ be the maximal number of disjoint balls of radius $r$ that can be put inside a ball of radius $s+r$ (such a number does exist). $N$ depends on $s/r$ and $d$ only.

You can construct as you did, thanks to Zorn's Lemma, a family $(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of subsets of $A$ such that $A_{i+1}$ is a non empty maximal $s$-separated subset of $A \setminus (A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{i})$, or if $A=A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{i}$, take $A_{i+1}=\emptyset$.

Let's show that there is only finitely many non empty $A_i$'s. Assume $A_{N+2} \neq \emptyset$ and take $x \in A_{N+2}$. Since $A$ is $r$-separated in $\mathbb{R}^d$, the ball $B(x,s)$ meets at most $N$ $A_i$'s. So there exists an integer $1 \leqslant n \leqslant N+1$ such that $B(x,s) \cap A_n = \emptyset$. But then $A_n \cup \{ x \}$ is in $A \setminus (A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{n-1})$, is $s$-separated and $A_n \neq A_n \cup \{ x \}$ , which contradicts the maximality of $A_n$ in $A \setminus (A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{n-1})$. This shows that $A_{N+2}=\emptyset$ and implies by construction $A=A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{N+1}$ ($A_{N+1}$ may be empty but for the finiteness it's okay).

Comment: Great answer. But comparing the N's in your paragraphs 2 and 4. I think you really want your N to be the maximal cardinality of r-separated points that can be contained in the ball of radius s.

Comment: Yes, that should be the number of disjoint radius-$r$ balls inside a ball of radius $s+r$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball